# What is the inverse of INTERCAL select operator?

Tags: bit-manipulation, intercal

The INTERCAL select operator denoted by sqiggle(~) takes a selection of bits and compresses them to one end of a word.

Section 3.4.1 of the THE INTERCAL PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE
REVISED REFERENCE MANUAL states:

> The select operator takes from the first operand whichever bits correspond to 1’s in the second operand, and
>   packs these bits to the right in the result. Both operands are automatically padded on the left with zeros to
>   32 bits before the selection takes place, so the variable types are unrestricted. If more than 16 bits are
>   selected, the result is a 32-bit value, otherwise it is a 16-bit value. For example, #179˜#201 (binary value
>   10110011˜11001001) selects from the first argument the 8th, 7th, 4th, and 1st from last bits, namely, 1001,
>   which = 9. But #201˜#179 selects from binary 11001001 the 8th, 6th, 5th, 2nd, and 1st from last bits, giving
>   10001 = 17. #179˜#179 has the value 31, while #201˜#201 has the value 15.

Is there a standard way of inverting this operation in INTERCAL or any other language?

And does the inverse have a name?

Comment: There is no inverse, since non-selected bits are just gone

Comment: OTOH if you meant more of an "opposite" and not a true inverse, you may find something interesting [here](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e)

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!